# How to fire ng-change event on input type number in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field on which I want to fire ng-change event whenever value gets changed, but unfortunately it is nor working at all. Any suggestion?

```
 <input ng-change="myfunction()" type="number" id="BI5" name="age" class="form-control" ng-model="numberField" />
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what "Not working at all" means in this case? And maybe add the code of `myfunction` and some context. I don't think that there is a general problem with `ng-change` and `type="number"`.

Comment: I have function on my scope "myfunction" which I want to execute on input type number which is not working..ng-keup, ng-click work fine for other inputs even the ng-change event work fine for select field. But I want to fire ng-change event on input type number which is not working..Any suggestio?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `ng-model`? I think it may be required.

Comment: It is already there, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$watch('scope')` should work, but it would be nice to be able to call a function instead of watching the scope change.